# Ruby: Assigning an object to a variable

Tags: ruby, class, instance

I have a piece of Ruby code I don't understand:

```
Line = Struct.new(name, "example")  // what happens here?

def foo(lines)
  lines.map { |z|
    Line.new(name, z[:specific])  // equal to 'Struct.new'?
  }
end
```

Does it mean that `Line` is an alias for `Struct` now? Or what else happens here?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253896

Answer (score 1):

`Line` is new class, one returned by `Struct.new`. `Struct` is a helper class that allows you to easily create classes with accessor methods to fields with names given as its constructor arguments. It might be confusing at first, but in Ruby classes are just another type of objects, and so they can be created by methods.

You can get reference on how `Struct` works here:
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Struct.html

Answer (score 1):

The `Struct` is just shorthand notation for this class:

```
class Line
  def initialize(example, name)
    @example = example
    @name = name
  end

  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def name
    @name
  end

  def example=(example)
    @example = example
  end

  def example
    @example
  end
end
```

When you see `Line.new`, just think of it as an instance of the `Line` class.  The `Sruct` is just a quicker way of creating the `Line` class.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that `Line` is an alias for `Struct` now?

No. That would be something like

```
Line = Struct
```

> ```
> Line = Struct.new(name, "example")  // what happens here?
> ```

1. Dereference the constant `Struct`
2. send the message `name` without arguments to `self`
3. send the message `new` with two arguments to the object returned in 1, the first argument is the object returned in 2., the second argument is the literal string `"example"`
4. assign the object returned in 3. to the constant `Line`

> ```
> Line.new(name, z[:specific])  // equal to 'Struct.new'?
> ```

No, that's not how assignments work in Ruby. In Ruby, you don't assign an expression to a variable, the expression gets evaluated *first*, and *then* the *result* of that evaluation gets assigned to the variable *once*.

I.e. if you do something like

```
foo = gets
```

`gets` does *not* get called over and over again, every time you dereference `foo`, it gets called *once* when you assign to `foo` and then `foo` contains a reference to the object returned by `gets`.

Besides, even *if* it worked like you seem to think it does, then it *still* wouldn't be equal to `Struct.new` but rather to `Struct.new(name, "example").new`, because *that's* the expression that was on the right-hand side of the assignment to `Line` (but, like I said, it *doesn't* work like that).